# Sum fields only if less than at specific date

Tags: crystal-reports

I have the following formula in my report:

```
Sum ({payment_full.paydueamt}, {@Sortname plus ID} - 
Sum ({payments_full.paybalamt}, {@Sortname plus ID})
```

However I need it to only sum if this statement is true: **EDIT Corrected first field name**

```
If ({payments_full.paydate} < {?PaymentsAsOfDate})
```

I have tried the following without any change in the resulting total.

```
If ({payments_full.paydate}<{?PaymentsAsOfDate}) then
Sum ({payment_full.paydueamt}, {@Sortname plus ID} -
Sum ({payments_full.paybalamt}, {@Sortname plus ID}) else 0.0
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a formula

```
If {payments_full.paydate} < {?PaymentsAsOfDate} then 
{payment_full.paydueamt} - {payments_full.paybalamt}
else 0
```

- place that in details
- right click
- Insert Summary
- follow the prompts place where you want it

NOTE: if you don't want it in the detail section just delete it from that part of the report canvas

Comment: Would posting the report definition file help?

Answer (score 0):

If this formula appears in the footer, try using a Running Total instead. Running Totals can be specifically tailored to only sum specific records.

Set Evaluate to *Use a formula* and enter `{payments_full.payduedate} < {?PaymentsAsOfDate}`

[image: Running Total Wizard]`

Comment: Yes the formula is in a group footer.  I am not sure I follow what your suggestion is.  I have Crystal Reports 11 if the make any difference.

Comment: In the Field Explorer, there should be a section called "Running Total Fields" - Right click that, and select New. That will bring you to the wizard for Running Totals. Set the "Field to Summarize" to your formula, and put `{payments_full.payduedate} < {?PaymentsAsOfDate}` in the Use a Formula section.

Comment: When I select Running Totals Field it has the is in the formula. (onfirstrecord or ({GENERIC.timekey}<>Previous ({GENERIC.timekey})))

Comment: I added a screenshot to help show you the settings you'll want in your Running Total. The *field to summarize* should be the Amount Paid (by donor). Does that clear anything up?